# php How to receive multiple cout from exe file?

Tags: php, c++

I am new in php, and I have a code like:

```
<?php
   $output = exec("$cmd",$output);
   echo $output
?>
```

and the c++ code will be something like below(not accurate),

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{

for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
   cout<<a[i]=i<<endl;
}
    cout<<"2"<<endl;
    cout<<"3"<<endl;
}
```

so if I do like that the output will just be last cout value(just a "3" in here), I am wondering can I use some method to get all output like it runs in terminal, for example:
"0123423"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exec()` populates the second argument (a variable passed by reference) with an array of all output.  You are then overwriting that variable with the return value which is the last line of output.  So don't do that:

```
$last_line = exec($cmd, $all_output);

echo $last_line;
print_r($all_output);
```

Consider [system()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.system.php) or [passthru()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php) to just display the output.